# Obtain ip range for Azure IoT Hub for white-listing

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

We have have some devices running Azure IoT Edge runtime that we are installing at a customer location. The customer's site has no cellular connectivity so we need to connect the devices to IoT Hub through their network, which is closed down by default. They are asking us for the ip address/range of addresses to white-list for the devices. All answers I have found so far indicate that the ip of an IoT Hub can change without notice.

Since Edge devices are often run in factory scenarios like this, I am curious if this is still the case? Does my provisioned IoT Hub have an ip address or ip range that I can whitelist in our on-prem firewall?

Comment: I have added an update to my answer including private endpoints. Please see if this answers your question or clarify what you are still missing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get one fixed IP address for your hub, but at least the IP ranges are published, by region. See here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/iot-hub-feature-service-tags-is-now-generally-available/

[Direct link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519) to the download of the JSON file

//Update as of May-2020: IoT Hub now also supports [private endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/virtual-network-support). This means that you can reach an IoT Hub on a private IP address, for example when using an Azure Express Route or VPN. Since the OP was asking about on-prem firewalls, this might also be an alternative.